# Can't figure out why res.json() is not hit in Unit Test Coverage, Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-coverage

So I have a Unit Test Coverage being tracked by the karma-coverage-instanbul-reporter, when I look at the coverage report though, the:

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

portion of all of my Providers is never hit in the test. But I do have tests for those Providers, and am verifying that I'm getting a response.

Here is an example of on the functions I'm testing:

```
public getCampaigns(): Observable<CampaignsResponse> {
  return this.http.get(this.campaignsUrl).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Here is the test for this function:

```
describe("getCampaigns", () => {
  it("should return an Observable<CampaignsResponse>",
    inject([CampaignsService, MockBackend], (service: CampaignsService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
      // arrange
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => {
        connection.mockBackend(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
          body: JSON.stringify(mockCampaigns),
        })));
      });

      // act
      service.getCampaigns().subscribe((campaigns) => {
        // assert
        expect(campaigns.campaigns.length).toEqual(1);
   expect(campaigns.campaigns[0].id).toEqual(mockCampaigns.campaigns[0].id);
      expect(campaigns.campaigns[0].channelID).toEqual(mockCampaigns.campaigns[0].channelID);
      expect(campaigns.campaigns[0].name).toEqual(mockCampaigns.campaigns[0].name);
      expect(campaigns.campaigns[0].active).toEqual(mockCampaigns.campaigns[0].active);
      expect(campaigns.campaigns[0].createdAt).toEqual(mockCampaigns.campaigns[0].createdAt);
      expect(campaigns.campaigns[0].updatedAt).toEqual(mockCampaigns.campaigns[0].updatedAt);
    });
}));
```

});

But according to my test coverage res.json() is never hit inside the map function.

Does anyone have any ideas on why that might be? Is it possible that the Coverage report is just wrong or is mapping the code incorrectly back to TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Your `connection` has the type `MockConnection` instead of `any`, and `MockConnection` does not have a `mockBackend` property. Instead, it has a `mockRespond`. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockConnection-class.html

Try modifying the test like this:

```
// arrange
mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
  connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
    body: JSON.stringify(mockCampaigns),
  })));
});
```

Comment: Well when I leave it as `mockBackend` it does execute the test correctly, so I do think that the `connection` variable does have a `mockBackend` property. But, when I do try with the `mockRespond` I'm still seeing the same Code Coverage analytics that `res.json()` is not getting hit.